# Why I obtain a syntax error when I try to insert a cycle output into an unordered list?

Tags: php, html, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I am very new in PHP and WordPress development and I have the following problem trying to insert some HTML code into the posts loop.

I tried something like it:

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
    <ul>
    // Start the Loop.
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        /*
         * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
         * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
         * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
         */

        <li>
        get_template_part('contentArchive', get_post_format());
        </li>

    endwhile;
    </ul>


    endwhile;
?>
```

As you can see I want an **unordered list** (the **< ul>**tag) and into it I want put the one list element (the **< li>** tag) for each interation of the while cycle but Aptana Studio give me a **syntax error** message on the **< ul>** and on the **< li>**

Why? Where is the problem? How can I fix it?

Tnx

Comment: Probably the fact that you're switching between php code and raw html markup without indicating that you're doing so with `?>` and `<?php` tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you aren't closing your PHP tags, you need to use echo calls to push output to the DOM.

```
<?php
if (have_posts()) :
    echo '<ul>';
    // Start the Loop.
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

        /*
         * Include the post format-specific template for the content. If you want to
         * use this in a child theme, then include a file called called content-___.php
         * (where ___ is the post format) and that will be used instead.
         */

        echo '<li>';
        get_template_part('contentArchive', get_post_format());
        echo '</li>';

    endwhile;
    echo '</ul>';


    endwhile;
?>
```